# Why does Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition show only 20% of my available memory?

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory

Fellow Techies-- I have a LENOVO x3650 X6/x64 based Windows server with 4 18 cores/36 logical processors-- with installed physical memory (ram) @1.5 TB, total virtual memory @1.5 TB. However, I am showing only 295 GB of available physical memory and only 297 GB of available virtual memory. What's the story? Does the Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition, version 6.3.9600, build 9600 cause the limitation? I know in the 2008 windows universe of products, there was difference between the Enterprise edition and the Standard edition--but the naming convention for the 2012 server editions is different. There is a data center class of windows products for windows server 2012--is this the equivalent? Am I going down the wrong path? Should I be looking at a different explanation as to why I am only showing 20% of what I think should be available?

[image]

Comment: No, something else is wrong. It supports [up to 4 TB of RAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: OK.  Basically I'm a database engineer. I only noticed this issue when the calculus I had in place for a workload estimate went dreadfully wrong over the weekend. While SQL Server was able to "see" the installed memory, once the workload was in play, only the available memory was able to be utilized. Outside of someting Lenovo specific, is there anything else I can look at?

Comment: Sometimes placement of the RAM sticks matters, but looking up this server I see you've maxed it out. It's hard to put RAM sticks in the wrong slots when there won't be any slots free. The only concern now would be if some of the RAM sticks are unsupported (wrong timings, etc). You may need to visit the BIOS/UEFI config to resolve this.

Comment: Have you checked Task Manager for applications hogging your memory?

Comment: Where are you getting the hardware configuration from? The x3650 M5 only supports **2 processors** according to the datasheet. http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/systems/servers/racks/systemx/x3650-m5/#tab-tech_specs

Comment: tfrederick, I'm pulling the configuration info from the System Information window.

Comment: Does the firmware properly reports 1.5 TB of RAM? Did you try booting some other OS, like a Linux live CD or USB thumbdrive? That could sort out if the problem is hardware or software.

Comment: What do you see in BIOS ? And can you update the firmware / drivers and check the results?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `Memory rank sparing` and/or `Memory mirroring` enabled.

**Memory mirroring:** Only half of your total memory is available for use.

**Memory rank sparing:** The total memory available in the system is reduced by the amount of memory allocated for the spare ranks.